# Split string and store in hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string of the format :

```
my $string = "this -is -a -test=2 -value=1 -data=num -string=8";
```

Basically, this is a some sort of cmd line format where we have a option, followed by some value.
I want to split this string so as to create a hash so as to store each option with its value.

my hash should look like :

```
my %hash = (
"this" => "",
"is"   => "",
"test" => "2",
"string" => "8",
);
```

Can this be done in one single line in perl ?

Comment: why you are ignoring `"-value"`, `"-a"` and `"-data"` from the string in hash?

Comment: And why is `this` inside the hash?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression. Note that options without a value like `is` will be stored as `undef`, whereas options with an empty parameter like `empty=` will be stored as a null string

Your parameter `this` isn't found because it doesn't start with a hyphen `-`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "this -is -a -test=2 -empty= -value=1 -data=num -string=8";

my %options = $string =~ /-(\w+)(?:=(\S*))?/g;

use Data::Dump;
dd \%options;
```

#### output

```
{
  a => undef,
  data => "num",
  empty => "",
  is => undef,
  string => 8,
  test => 2,
  value => 1,
}
```

Comment: I don't even have a Perl compiler installed, but I think I will install one now thanks to your input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Always wise if you're answering Perl questions! Go for Strawberry if you're on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Although using a regular expression will work here, you should consider using `Getopt::Long` for any non-trivial command line argument parsing.

[perldoc Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)